# May the gravitational constant $G$ be a *functional* of all fields on spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, field-theory, physical-constants

Is it theoretically possible that the $G$ constant in Einstein's equation be a ***functional*** of all fields present in a given spacetime ?
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
G_{\mu \nu} + \Lambda \, g_{\mu \nu} = -\, \frac{8 \pi}{c^4} \, G[g, \phi] \, T_{\mu \nu}.
\end{equation}
Since it's by hypothesis a *global functional* of some sort defined over all of spacetime, it's still a constant independant of position (so the Bianchi identity and local conservation of energy-momentum still apply), but $G$ may change for different spacetimes and fields configurations.  In a sense, it's "scale" dependant.

In other words : Given an asymptotically flat spacetime with matter and total energy $E$ (ADM or Tolman mass), could $G$ be dependant on energy : $G(E)$ ?

Are there any published studies about this idea ?

And as a generalisation, what about the other "constants" of nature ?

Could the cosmological constant $\Lambda$ and the *fine structure constant* $\alpha \equiv k \, e^2 / \hbar c$ also be some functionals of fields over spacetime ?

What would be the arguments *against* this idea ?

Note : I'm not asking about *position* dependance, which isn't the same thing at all : $G = G[g, \phi] \ne G(x)$ (notice the square brackets!).  I'm talking about a *functional*, like the fields *action* : $S \equiv S[g, \phi]$.  So maybe $G$ is proportional to $S$, or any other functional.

---

**EDIT :**  May the *dark matter* be explained by such an hypothesis ?  If $G$ depends on the scale (i.e the energy involved), then gravity isn't responding the same at our solar system's scale, and at a galactic scale.

This idea has some *machian* feel, in a way, since properties of curved spacetime may depend on the amount of matter/energy in it, from its $G(E)$ !

Since some people appear to have difficulties with the idea of a functional (not a *function*), I'm giving a naive *example* of what $G$ *may* look like, according to the idea above.  For some real scalar field $\phi(x) \sim \mathrm{L}^{-1}$ :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
G[g, \phi] = G_0 \, \sqrt{ 1 + G_0^2 \int_{\mathcal{M}} \big( g^{\mu \nu} (\partial_{\mu} \, \phi)(\partial_{\nu} \, \phi) \big)^{2} \, \sqrt{- g} \: d^4 x + \ldots },
\end{equation}
where $G_0 \sim \mathrm{L}^2$ is a "naked" gravitationnal constant.  The other terms are "scale dependant corrections".  So the real gravitational coupling constant $G$ depends *globaly* on the matter content in the whole of spacetime, or on *the scale we consider to do the calculations*.

---

**EDIT 2 :**  Here's a small argument in favor of the previous idea.  Ever noticed that both $G$ and $\alpha$ have physical dimensions (i.e units) that depend on the spacetime dimensions $D$ ? (this is well known.  Just examine the Poisson equation : $\nabla^2 \phi = 4 \pi G \rho$, where the density $\rho$ depends on the $D - 1$ space dimensions) :
\begin{align}\tag{3}
G &\sim \mathrm{L}^{D - 2},
&\alpha &\sim \mathrm{L}^{D - 4}.
\end{align}
Then if their value necessarily changes with the dimensionality $D$ of spacetime, why should they stay the same for all spacetimes of a given dimensionality ?

Comment: And what about the possibility that our problems with dark matter - which happens at some large scale - may be explained by a different $G$ at that scale ?

Comment: Doesn't condensed matter physics do stuff like this, introduce a new matter field $\phi$, then pretend $\langle\phi\rangle$ is a coupling constant of some sort?

Comment: As per arguments against this, it's horribly nonlocal...

Comment: I agree it's highly non-local, but since $G$ is still just a constant, we could in principle solve for any $G$, then compute it after we know the dynamics of the fields.  This is viable only for analytical solutions, I guess (like the Schwarzschild solution), which is pretty limited.  This non-locality would be essentially the same for any *machian* theory.  Or maybe it's viable for successive approximations, if we already know the functional dependance of $G$.

Comment: Is the notation $g$ supposed to refer to the metric? If so, then you have a problem with the equivalence principle. Is $\phi$ referring to matter fields? If so, then why can't this just be absorbed into $T$?

Comment: @BenCrowell, yes $g$ refer to the metric.  In what aspect there's a problem with the equivalence principle ?  Does $g$ in the action has a problem with the equ. principle ?  And $\phi$ (from $G$) can't be absorbed into $T$ because $G[g, \phi]$ is a *functional* (not a *function*) of $g$ and $\phi$ (like in the action $S[g, \phi]$).  Again, the idea is that $G$ is not a function of $x$ via the fields, it's a global constant defined from the fields over all of spacetime.

Comment: It's not only no local in space, it is also acausal in time. The metric in a future 'cosmological' time would affect today's G. The present would be affected by the future. And how does it know? There are theories of G being a field, but teventhough those can be written to preserve causality they still have a hard time jiving with observations. And yes, I can see why pseudo Machian, G depends on spacetime, and the extra scalar field. But it doesn't help any.

Comment: Anyway, Isn't your proposal a proposal for a pet theory? I think those are excluded from this site.

Comment: I agree the time correlation may feel weird.  It would be better if it was total energy instead : $G = G(E)$.  Is there a way to define invariant topological constants from the metric and fields on the space section only ?

Comment: *In what aspect there's a problem with the equivalence principle ? Does g in the action has a problem with the equ. principle ?* Yes. One way of stating the equivalence principle is simply that only curvature (2nd derivatives of the metric) is observable, not the metric or its 1st derivative. The 1st derivative of the metric is basically the gravitational field, which you obviously can't detect according to the e.p. The metric itself is basically the gravitational potential, and there are even more obvious reasons why a potential is not directly detectable.

Comment: @BenCrowell, I don't think there's a problem with the equ. principle, even if $G$ depends on the metric or curvature, because you still can find *locally* a reference frame in which the metric is the Minkowski metric, and the partial derivatives of $g$ (or the conection) are 0, wathever what value is $G$.  This is the true meaning of the qu. principle.  You still can eliminate gravity *localy*.  $G$ has nothing to do with this, if it's a constant.  My idea doesn't change anything here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are suggesting that the gravitational constant is a "running constant", then you might want to look into the Asymptotic Safety programme in Quantum Gravity.

Unfortunately, however, it seems there are theoretical difficulties with a running $G$, namely there's no consistent "universal" theoretic way to do it below the Planck scale. For more on this problem, see:

- Mohamed M. Anber, John F. Donoghue,
  "On the running of the gravitational constant".
  [arXiv:1111.2875](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2875), 13 pages.

Comment: What do you mean by "running" constant ?  A scalar field slowly changing with position or time ?  $G(t)$ ??  Geez, again, this is not what I'm talking about.  I'm talking about a constant that depends on the scale we choose to make the calculations :  $G(E) \ne G(t)$.

Comment: @Cham in QFT, certain fields have their coupling constant "run" (or change values) with the energy scale. That is to say, have $G=G(E)$...which is what you're talking about...